# Will the WebBrowser ActiveX control continue working after June 2022?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, activex

Microsoft announced the end of Internet Explorer by June 2022.
However I cannot find any information on how this will affect the old WebBrowser Active X control. As far as I know it is based on the Internet Explorer.
I know there are new versions of the .net wrapper and for the Delphi wrapper, which are based on Edge.
Unfortunately my legacy application is made with Delphi XE3, so it cannot make use of the new Edge control. Migrating to new Delphi is a nightmare with all those breaking changes in my third-party components and in Delphi itself. I doubt I can make it until June.

*Mind that I am not talking about Active X controls running inside IE.*

*I am talking about IE running inside desktop applications.*

So my question is: What will happen to my application in June 2022? Will it continue working? Will it crash? Will it show an empty space in place of the control? Will throw an exception?

Comment: Only the desktop app is phased out, but components should stay: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549 see "IE mode" discussions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#ie-mode-supports-the-following-internet-explorer-functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will continue working :-)

Simon's comment pointed to [MSHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSHTML), which is not only the browser engine. MSHTML also includes the COM interface (and ActiveX is just a marketing name for COM). MSHTML will be continued at least until 2029.