# Will the retirement of Internet Explorer kill the InternetExplorer Platform API?

Tags: internet-explorer, vb6

According to Microsoft, [Internet Explorer is being retired](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/05/19/the-future-of-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-is-in-microsoft-edge/) on June 15, 2022.

At what point will the [InternetExplorer Platform API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v=vs.85)) cease working as a result of this change?

Is there any documentation which describes the specifics and timing for sun-setting that API?

Or will it automatically transition to working with [Microsoft Edge Internet Explorer (IE) Mode](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/ie-mode)?

Or is it not in [the scope of retirement](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549) as it's part of the "Internet Explorer platform (MSHTML/Trident), including WebOC"? [Another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71797074/2266979) says ActiveX will survive due to being part of that extended platform? (Microsoft [affirmatively states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#ie-mode-supports-the-following-internet-explorer-functionality) ActiveX is part of Edge Internet Explorer mode.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like what you say in the last paragraph, the InternetExplorer Platform API is not in the scope of retirement. You can still use it.

You can also find this in the [retirement FAQ blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549):

> These IE COM objects have been restored to their original functionality as of the Windows 11 November 2021 “C” update and the Windows 10 February 2022 “B” update (for versions 1809 and later). The COM scenarios will also continue to work after the IE11 desktop application is disabled after June 15, 2022.